# Typescript: when to make custom definitions?

Tags: typescript

When programming fully with TypeScript what are appropriate cases when one would want to create custom definitions/declarations manually?

I see something when overloading is needed and so need to create multiple definitions for one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When programming fully with TypeScript what are appropriate cases when one would want to create custom definitions/declarations manually

Normally you would create *declaration files* for external systems.

Within your code you would write a declaration for common structures used in your project e.g. if you find yourself using something like `Person` a lot you would declare it:

```
type Person = {
   displayName: string
}
```

## More

Reading some documentation is highly recommended. I have a free book as well: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html